# ValueError: Shapes are incompatible in Tensorflow LSTM using RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

#### Problem

Given several input feature (sequences) I want to train a LSTM RNN making (one-hot encoded) multi-class predictions for several features at the same time. That is, my input `X` has shape `(observations, sequence length, features_in)` while the output `y` has shape `(observations, class_prediction, features_out)`. This particular setting requires that the softmax activation function of the final layer is applied only along one axis which (afaik) can be achieved by using a `Lambda` layer. The output I want is similar to what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55831526/multiple-softmax-in-dense-layer), but with the difference that the individual "softmax arrays" are organized as another dimension. Actually, in my case, I'm using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55833668/3050730) from the same thread.

Now, training this model seems to work as expected (at least no errors are thrown). However, when using `RandomizedSearchCV` to find the hyperparameters, the following error is raised:

```py
ValueError: in user code:

    /home/nrieger/anaconda3/envs/tf26/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:853 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /home/nrieger/anaconda3/envs/tf26/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:842 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /home/nrieger/anaconda3/envs/tf26/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1286 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /home/nrieger/anaconda3/envs/tf26/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2849 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /home/nrieger/anaconda3/envs/tf26/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3632 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/nrieger/anaconda3/envs/tf26/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:835 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /home/nrieger/anaconda3/envs/tf26/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:788 train_step
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
    /home/nrieger/anaconda3/envs/tf26/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:201 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /home/nrieger/anaconda3/envs/tf26/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/losses.py:141 __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    /home/nrieger/anaconda3/envs/tf26/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/losses.py:245 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /home/nrieger/anaconda3/envs/tf26/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/nrieger/anaconda3/envs/tf26/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/losses.py:1665 categorical_crossentropy
        return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    /home/nrieger/anaconda3/envs/tf26/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/nrieger/anaconda3/envs/tf26/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/backend.py:4839 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    /home/nrieger/anaconda3/envs/tf26/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1161 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 3, 9, 2) and (None, 3, 9) are incompatible
```

#### MWE

*Note: The `axis` argument in `CategoricalCrossentropy` was added only in Tensorflow version >= 2.6. That is, you won't be able to run the MWE with TF v2.5 or below.*

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy.random import standard_normal, choice
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, LSTM, Reshape, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.activations import softmax
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical


def build_model(input_shape, n_neurons, output_shape):
    inp = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = LSTM(
        n_neurons,
        return_sequences=False,
        input_shape=[None, input_shape[1]],
    )(inp)
    x = Dense(np.product(output_shape))(x)
    x = Reshape(output_shape)(x)
    out = Lambda(lambda x: softmax(x, axis=1))(x)
    model = Model(inp, out)

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
    loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(axis=1)
    model.compile(
        loss=loss,
        optimizer=optimizer,
    )
    return model


n_observations = 100
sequence_length = 5
n_features_in = 7

n_classes = 3
target_classes = [0, 1, 2] * 3
n_features_out = len(target_classes)

X = standard_normal((n_observations, sequence_length, n_features_in))
y = [to_categorical(choice(target_classes, n_features_out, replace=False)).T for i in range(n_observations)]
y = np.stack(y)

X.shape  # (observations, sequence_length, features_in) -> (100, 5, 7)
y.shape  # (observations, target classes, features_out) -> (100, 3, 9)

# Fit model (this works!)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
model = build_model(X.shape[1:], 10, y.shape[1:])
_ = model.fit(X, y, epochs=4)

# Randomized Search CV (ERROR!)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
keras_reg = keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasRegressor(build_model)
param_distribs = {
    'n_neurons'     : np.arange(1, 1000),
    'input_shape'   : [X.shape[1:]],
    'output_shape'  : [y.shape[1:]],
}

grid_search_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(keras_reg, param_distribs, n_iter=2)
grid_search_cv.fit(X, y, epochs=4)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using keras-tuner?

Comment: I didn't know about keras-tuner. I'll give it a try to see if the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can easily solve this with the `keras-tuner`:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from numpy.random import standard_normal, choice
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, LSTM, Reshape, Lambda
from tensorflow.keras.activations import softmax
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import keras_tuner as kt

def build_model(hp):
    inp = Input(shape=(5, 7))
    x = LSTM(
        hp.Int('n_neurons',min_value=1,max_value=1000, step=1),return_sequences=False,input_shape=[None, 7])(inp)
    x = Dense(np.product((3, 9)))(x)
    x = Reshape((3, 9))(x)
    out = Lambda(lambda x: softmax(x, axis=1))(x)
    model = Model(inp, out)
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
    loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(axis=1)
    model.compile(loss=loss,optimizer=optimizer)
    return model

n_observations = 100
sequence_length = 5
n_features_in = 7
n_classes = 3
target_classes = [0, 1, 2] * 3
n_features_out = len(target_classes)
X = standard_normal((n_observations, sequence_length, n_features_in))
y = [to_categorical(choice(target_classes, n_features_out, replace=False)).T for i in range(n_observations)]
y = np.stack(y)

tuner = kt.RandomSearch(
    build_model,
    objective='loss',
    max_trials=5)
tuner.search(X, y, epochs=5)
best_model = tuner.get_best_models()[0]
```

You can use `HyperParameters.Int` to define a range you want to test out.